# Android ListView window leak error

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am having a bit of a problem on my hands and I'm going to need a little.  My app keeps crashing and when I look at the stacktrace this is what I get back...

```
theproblemsolver.ListView has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d0e800 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-234,72} that was originally added here
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.theproblemsolver.ListView has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d0e800 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-234,72} that was originally added here
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at com.theproblemsolver.ListView$LoadAllData.onPreExecute(ListView.java:85)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at com.theproblemsolver.ListView.onCreate(ListView.java:52)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-27 11:05:56.119: E/WindowManager(913):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can somebody please tell me what this is and what I can do to fix this..

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et;
    Button getanswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button getanswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        getanswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }


        });
    } 
}
```

ListView Activity

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;

    private static String URI = "http://example.com/json";;

    //JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURI(URI); 

     final String TAG_RESULTS = "ResultsSet";
     final String TAG_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     final String TAG_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     final String TAG_QUESTION = "Question";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_ANSWERS = "Answers";

            JSONArray ResultsSet = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    android.widget.ListView lv = getListView(); 

    new LoadAllData().execute();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {


        }
    });

}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == 100) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURI(URI);
                    ResultsSet = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

                   for(int i = 0; i < ResultsSet.length(); i++) {
                       JSONObject r = ResultsSet.getJSONObject(i);
                       String Subject = r.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                       String NumAnswers = r.getString(TAG_NUMANSWERS);

                       JSONObject Question = r.getJSONObject(TAG_QUESTION);
                       String Content = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);
                       String ChosenAnswer = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                       String Answers = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_ANSWERS);

                       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                       map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, Subject);
                       map.put(TAG_NUMANSWERS, NumAnswers);
                   }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;


        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URI) {

            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                        R.layout.row,
                        new String[] { TAG_SUBJECT, TAG_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers });

                setListAdapter(adapter);



                }
            });

        }
}}
```

SimpleListItem

```
 public class SingleListItem extends Activity {

    TextView subject;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.singlelistitem);

    subject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Subject2);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String Subject = i.getStringExtra("TAG_SUBJECT");
    subject.setText(Subject);

    }
}
```

I'm putting in two Activities that's in my project and the reason I didn't post them is because I didn't know if they are important or not

JSONParsser Activity

```
public class JSONParsser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    EditText et;

    public JSONParsser () {
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromURI(String URI) {

        try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            URI website = new URI("http://example.com/json");
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return jObj;

        }finally{}

    }{

    }}
```

InstanceOfJSONParsser Activity

```
public class JSONParserInstance {

    JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();

    public String URI;

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURI(URI);


     private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "ResultsSet";
     private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     private static final String TAG_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     private static final String TAG_QUESTION = "Question";
     private static final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     private static final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     private static final String TAG_QUESTION_ANSWERS = "Answers";

            JSONArray ResultsSet = null; {

    try {
       ResultsSet = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

       for(int i = 0; i < ResultsSet.length(); i++){
           JSONObject r = ResultsSet.getJSONObject(i);

           String Subject = r.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
           String NmAnswers = r.getString(TAG_NUMANSWERS);

           JSONObject Question = r.getJSONObject(TAG_QUESTION);
           String Content = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);
           String ChosenAnswer = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
           String Answers = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_ANSWERS);

       }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();

}}}
```

Comment: not so sure about what is causing the problem but two things look weird. One you create map in doInBackground and don't use it at all. Second you run code via runOnUiThread in onPostExecute. AFAIK onPostExecute is run on UI thread anyway.

Comment: It _looks_ like you're calling `pDialog.dismiss();` when the Activity has already exited. Try dismissing it in `onPause()` to make sure it's closed properly when the Activity deactivates.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your AsyncTask has a strong reference to your Activity. Please consider using a static class with a WeakReference instead.

```
private static class StaticAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
    private WeakReference<Activity> mActivityRef;

    private StaticAsyncTask(Activity callingActivity) {
        mActivityRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(callingActivity);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO: Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // TODO: Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        Activity activity = mActivityRef.get();
        if (activity != null) {
            // TODO: Do stuff with my non-null activity
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you write this asynctask with my code so I can see an example

Comment: I'm having a hard time deciphering what your AsyncTask is trying to accomplish (leverage the three parameters well! AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>).

Basically, any time you want to use a field or method inside the Activity, or access a View in the Activity, get() from the WeakReference and see if  it is valid. I would recommend refraining from accessing the Activity from inside doInBackground.