# WindowLeak error in Android

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am currently working on a Android project and I have ran into one particular error. The error I'm having is a window leak error. I only thing I can think of that is causing this problem is my layouts for my project or if it was ListView Actvity but I'm really not sure because I have never seen this error before. So I was just hoping if somebody could tell me what is causing this error and what I can do to fix it.

```
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952): Activity com.theproblemsolver.ListView has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d0f620 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-234,72} that was originally added here
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.theproblemsolver.ListView has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d0f620 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-234,72} that was originally added here
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at com.theproblemsolver.ListView$LoadAllData.onPreExecute(ListView.java:86)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at com.theproblemsolver.ListView.onCreate(ListView.java:52)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-29 13:43:59.891: E/WindowManager(952):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ListView:

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;

    private static String URI = "http://example.com/json";;

    //JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURI(URI);

     final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     final String TAG_QUESTION = "Question";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
     final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    

            JSONArray Question = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    //questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    android.widget.ListView lv = getListView(); 

    new LoadAllData().execute();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {


        }
    });

}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == 100) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            //JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURI(URI);

            try {

                    Question = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTION);

                   for(int i = 0; i < Question.length(); i++) {
                       JSONObject q = Question.getJSONObject(i);

                       String Subject = q.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                       String NumAnswers = q.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
                       String ChosenAnswers = q.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                       String Content = q.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                       JSONObject Answers = q.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS);
                       String Answer = Answers.getString(TAG_ANSWER);

                     questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                       map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                       map.put(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS, NumAnswers);

                       questionList.add(map);
                   }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URI) {

            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                        R.layout.row,
                        new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers });

                setListAdapter(adapter);



                }
            });

        }
}}
```

Row.xml Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/NumAnswers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's new from the [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906060/android-listview-window-leak-error)? You still need to see that the dialog is dismissed before the activity exits.

Comment: the `runOnUiThread(....`  you have in your onPostExecute is redundant,  the onPostExecute method already runs on the ui thread.  you could should remove this usage.